# Change part of URL string for images with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database, the image links are saved in the format like `http://www.old.com/image1.jpg`. But I had to change the domains of the images and the new links appear like `images.new.com/image1.jpg`. I have been changing the images links with jQuery with the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');;
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('www.old', 'images.new'));
    });
});
```

But I am wondering is there any way to change part of the URL strings with PHP. I am getting the image URLs with the following PHP function.

```
<?php
   $imageQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT imageURL FROM images WHERE album = 'UK' ORDER BY date ASC");
   $images = $imageQuery->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $images = array_chunk($images, 2);
   ?>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4" id="box1">
      <?php foreach (array_column($images, 0) as $image): ?>
      <img class="img-fluid" src="<?= $image['imageURL']; ?>">
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4" id="box2">
      <?php foreach (array_column($images, 1) as $image): ?>
      <img class="img-fluid" src="<?= $image['imageURL']; ?>">
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

With PHP how can I echo the new links for the images directly here in the img src? `<img class="img-fluid" src="<?= $image['imageURL']; \\modified link here ?>">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has it's own method for replacing strings, [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). The equivalent to your jQuery in PHP is:

```php
str_replace('www.old', 'images.new', $image['imageURL'])
```

A *better idea* would be to update the values in your database.

An *even better* idea would be to not store the duplicate root URLs anywhere, and stitch them together in the application if you need absolute URLs, for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Seems like saving the URLs without root would be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively convert the text in the sql select statement:

```
SELECT REPLACE(imageURL, 'www.old', 'images.new') AS imageURL FROM ...
```

By using AS imageURL none of the rest of the code would need to change.